# Add title in li tag using angular js

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am using third party control and that control generate `<div>` containing `<li>` tag.

now i am trying to give title attribute so when use hover on `<li>` tag then user can see tooltip.

below is code snippet.

```
<div id="drpDashboard_popup" class="e-ddl-popup" >
    <ul class="e-ul" role="listbox">
        <li id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" role="option" class="e-hover">New Dashboard</li>
        <li id="4ca2885b-1896-c0cf-24d3-08d24a2f5c7e" role="option" class="e-active">Another Dahsboard</li>
        <li id="4f99c665-b339-c99e-2038-08d26599a807" role="option" class="">DashboardSave</li>
        <li id="521ed554-5d6f-c3b9-9e83-08d24a2f456b" role="option" class="">First Dashboard</li>
        <li id="7d99d618-458f-cee5-07d9-08d25c41c8a1" role="option" class="">FiveCharts</li>
        <li id="43ee8bd7-c1b1-c179-4e2d-08d25c40855a" role="option" class="">ThreeChartsDB</li>
        <li id="a18c47fb-e097-cd77-66f3-08d24a2f867e" role="option" >Windows - Peak page File DB</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have jquery to add title in `<li>` tag. refer below jquery code.

```
$(function () {
    $(".e-ddl-popup").find("li").each(function () {
        $(this).mouseover(function () {
            $(this).attr('title', $(this).html());
        });
    });
});
```

but i want to do in angular js. there is `ng-mouseover` in angular but i don't know how to use it in my code because list is dynamically generated by third party custom control.

Comment: Just FYI the `mouseover` event is redundant, so you can do what you require in jQuery in a one-liner: `$('.e-ddl-popup li').prop('title', function() { return $(this).text(); });`

Comment: I prefer angular js for doing this task because of client requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a directive that perform adding title using jquery dynamic event binding (see https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler). So you have to put your component in an element that does not create dynamically (such as a simple div) then apply your directive to it:

```
<div component-container>
    <!-- put your component here -->
</div>
```

then your directive that changes titles is as follows:

```
app.directive("componentContainer", [function () {
        return {
            restrict: "C",
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                $(iElement).on('mouseover', 'li', function () {
                    $(this).attr('title', $(this).html());
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: I am getting error at JQuery. error shows "Expected '{'". and what is the use of iAttrs?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. iAttrs is collection of attributes in element that directive applies to. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive for more details.

Comment: div with e-ddl-popup class is dynamically generated by custom control so how i can give directive to that div?

Comment: You don't need to give directive to div because it hast class restrict so it must apply on every element that hast class `e-ddl-popup`. But I suspect to work on something that created dynamically. What component create this div? Is it an angular directive?